# Satipatthana sutta in english AUDIO

Tags: satipatthana, media

Is there a version of Satipatthana Sutta in **English AUDIO** . I have got the pali version but I do not understand the full meaning when I listen to it.The idea is to listen every day when I go to work and come home after work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the reading of Sally Clough with a calm soothing voice and intonation.

http://www.suttareadings.net/audio/mn.010.sclo.mp3

You can also find other Suttas read there.

Answer (score 4):

There are these [audio Dhamma talks on the *Satipatthana Sutta* by Ven. Bhikkhu Bodhi](http://bodhimonastery.org/a-systematic-study-of-the-majjhima-nikaya.html).

There are 10 talks. You can see an overview of the 10 talks [here](http://mirror1.birken.ca/dhamma_talks/indiv/Bodhi/06/MajjhimaNikayaLectures.htm).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a very 8 day workshop done by S.N. Goenka on the Satipatthana Sutta which takes you through the original Pali sutta followed by further elaboration

The disclosures:

- [Day 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NK0Q3wUqkOo)
- [Day 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJTuusCs4vI)
- [Day 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYihaYA-BJ4)
- [Day 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jL7hm98zqT4)
- [Day 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_OW9RcxyUc)
- [Day 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzKYcYpJolw)
- [Day 7A](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQYi9VfrsxU)
- [Day 7B](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQnQL9_npD8)

The same is available at: http://www.vridhamma.org/Discourses-on-Satipatthana-Sutta as a trascribed file and also sutta and it's traslation used for this discoure can fe found at: http://www.tipitaka.org/stp-pali-eng-parallel